# Why is Python matplot not starting from the point where my Data starts

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

Kindly follow the link above to see the output of graph and code

My data starts from 1995 but as the graph output shows there is a gap between origin point on x-axis and 1995, shouldn't 1995 taken as the origin point? If so, how do i change/set the origin point here

[image]

Comment: By default, `matplotlib` leaves a little bit space between the origin and the lowest data point (same goes for the upper right edge). You can change that with `plt.gca().set_xlim()` and `plt.gca().set_ylim()`. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) for details.

Comment: set limits accordingly , by default it leave some space